# Normal View creates form with hidden inputs?

Tags: 7, views, theming

Ive created a view which im rendering in a content type TPL file with this:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('shows_taxonomy_term_links', "block_1"); ?>
```

Im getting some really weird behaviour. The view is within a form element which has some hidden fields in it. Here is my View:

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'shows_taxonomy_term_links';
$view->description = 'A view to emulate Drupal core\'s handling of taxonomy/term.';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'Shows taxonomy term links';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['options']['query_comment'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'entity';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['view_mode'] = 'teaser';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
/* Field: Draggableviews: Content */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['id'] = 'draggableviews';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['field'] = 'draggableviews';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['element_default_classes'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['hide_alter_empty'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['draggableviews']['handler'] = 'draggableviews_handler_fieldapi';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['draggableviews']['hierarchy_handler'] = 'draggableviews_hierarchy_handler_native';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['draggableviews']['ajax'] = 0;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['draggableviews']['draggableviews']['draggableviews_handler_fieldapi'] = array(
  'field' => 'field_data_field_order_on_show_page:field_order_on_show_page_value',
);
/* Field: Content: Order on show page */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_order_on_show_page']['id'] = 'field_order_on_show_page';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_order_on_show_page']['table'] = 'field_data_field_order_on_show_page';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_order_on_show_page']['field'] = 'field_order_on_show_page';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['field_order_on_show_page']['settings'] = array(
  'thousand_separator' => ' ',
  'prefix_suffix' => 1,
);
/* Field: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['type']['field'] = 'type';
/* Sort criterion: Content: Order on show page (field_order_on_show_page) */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_order_on_show_page_value_1']['id'] = 'field_order_on_show_page_value_1';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_order_on_show_page_value_1']['table'] = 'field_data_field_order_on_show_page';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['field_order_on_show_page_value_1']['field'] = 'field_order_on_show_page_value';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID (with depth) */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['id'] = 'term_node_tid_depth';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['field'] = 'term_node_tid_depth';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['exception']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['title'] = '%1';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['default_argument_type'] = 'taxonomy_tid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['validate']['type'] = 'taxonomy_term';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['depth'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth']['break_phrase'] = TRUE;
/* Contextual filter: Content: Has taxonomy term ID depth modifier */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['id'] = 'term_node_tid_depth_modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['field'] = 'term_node_tid_depth_modifier';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['exception']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['term_node_tid_depth_modifier']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['operator'] = 'not in';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'show_brand' => 'show_brand',
);
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = '1';

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['enabled'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'taxonomy/term/%';

/* Display: Feed */
$handler = $view->new_display('feed', 'Feed', 'feed');
$handler->display->display_options['enabled'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'full';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = 15;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'rss';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'node_rss';
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'taxonomy/term/%/%/feed';
$handler->display->display_options['displays'] = array(
  'page' => 'page',
  'default' => 0,
);

/* Display: Block */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block', 'block_1');

/* Display: Block 2 */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block 2', 'block_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'table';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = array(
  'title' => 'title',
  'draggableviews' => 'draggableviews',
  'field_order_on_show_page' => 'field_order_on_show_page',
  'type' => 'type',
);
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['default'] = '-1';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['info'] = array(
  'title' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'draggableviews' => array(
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'field_order_on_show_page' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
  'type' => array(
    'sortable' => 0,
    'default_sort_order' => 'asc',
    'align' => '',
    'separator' => '',
    'empty_column' => 0,
  ),
);
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$translatables['shows_taxonomy_term_links'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('Title'),
  t('Content'),
  t('Order on show page'),
  t('Type'),
  t('All'),
  t('%1'),
  t('Page'),
  t('Feed'),
  t('Items per page'),
  t('- All -'),
  t('Offset'),
  t('« first'),
  t('‹ previous'),
  t('next ›'),
  t('last »'),
  t('Block'),
  t('Block 2'),
);
```

And this is outputted on the page:

```
<div class="view view-shows-taxonomy-term-links view-id-shows_taxonomy_term_links view-display-id-block_1 view-dom-id-13d1e8646a8723a982380a99b187d726">



      <div class="view-content">
      <div class="views-form"><form action="/tv-show/tv-show-1" method="post" id="views-form-shows-taxonomy-term-links-block-1" accept-charset="UTF-8"><div><input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" value="form-_0pe9Jy9jP9I6UJlbXsLE1DyTAVlSNbAqxzOZM28tZI">
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="views_form_shows_taxonomy_term_links_block_1">
  <div class="views-row views-row-1 views-row-odd views-row-first">

    <a href="/tv-show/tv-show-1/pictures/picture1">
        <div class="field field-name-field-shared-promo-image field-type-image field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://myurl/sites/ciuk/files/wallpaper2-promoimage.jpg" width="311" height="248"></div></div></div>        <div class="field field-name-field-shared-promo-text field-type-text-long field-label-hidden"><div class="field-items"><div class="field-item even"><div class="owlcarousel-fields-68" style="opacity: 1; display: block;"><div class="owl-wrapper-outer"><div class="owl-wrapper" style="left: 0px; display: block;"><div class="owl-item"><div class="item-0">The Teddies Picture</div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div>    </a>

  </div>
  <div class="views-row views-row-2 views-row-even">
```

Ive also noticed the row style output in the theming information is strange:

```
Row style output: .tpl.php, --shows-taxonomy-term-links.tpl.php, --block.tpl.php, --shows-taxonomy-term-links--block.tpl.php, --default.tpl.php, --default.tpl.php, --block-1.tpl.php, --shows-taxonomy-term-links--block-1.tpl.php
```

Answer (score 3):

I think it's caused by [Draggable Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/draggableviews) 7.x-2.1

I just did a test on one of my Views and it didn't have the **views-form** form tag until I added the field **Draggableviews: Content (Content)** to it.  Even in an anonymous session everything in the "view-content" div was wrapped in a form tag with an ID with the prefix **views-form-**.

I discovered this while developing a View that outputs a form in every node result and the individual forms weren't working because they were all nested in the **Draggable Views** added parent form tag.

I resolved this by applying the patch mentioned at:  https://www.drupal.org/node/2495751#comment-9965493

I believe this issue has been addressed in 7.x-2.x-dev

Comment: Impressive answer. I'll be sure to keep a look out for this behaviour.